# First book for calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am in high school (18 years old) and I'd like to buy a calculus book.
I'm interested in Spivak's calculus book.
I love mathematics so I am motivated, but I don't want to read something too advanced neither a simple and basic textbook.

Comment: Consider checking out Apostol's Calculus I & II. They are rigorous texts, interluded with some nice intuition and useful exercises.

Comment: Gilbert Strang's book "Calculus" is available for free at https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-001-calculus-online-textbook-spring-2005/textbook/ . It's a great book. Not as rigorous as Spivak's book, but a great book for beginner-to-intermediate calculus. The student study guide and instructors manual is also available at the above link.